# Unable to resolve service for type 'EventLog.Services.Interfaces.IEventLogService'

Tags: c#, .net-core, events, dependency-injection, event-handling

I know this issue is being caused by how I have registered my services. I am just not sure why. If anyone can offer me any help as to what I am doing wrong I will be very grateful.

Here is my error message:

> Error while validating the service descriptor
> 'ServiceType: ProductAPI.IntegrationEvents.IProductIntegrationEventService Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType:
> ProductAPI.IntegrationEvents.ProductIntegrationEventService':
> Unable to resolve service for type 'EventLog.Services.Interfaces.IEventLogService' while attempting to activate 'ProductAPI.IntegrationEvents.ProductIntegrationEventService'.

I also know I have not implemented IEventLogService correctly. But again I am not sure why.

Here is where I have registered the service:

> 

```
services.AddTransient<Func<DbConnection, IEventLogService>>(
               sp => (DbConnection connection) => new EventLogService(connection));
```

This is my IEventLogService interface:

> `public interface IEventLogService`

```
{
    Task<IEnumerable<IntegrationEventLogEntry>> RetrieveEventLogsPendingToPublishAsync(Guid transactionId);
    Task SaveEventAsync(IntegrationEvent @event, IDbContextTransaction transaction);
    Task MarkEventAsPublishedAsync(Guid eventId);
    Task MarkEventAsInProgressAsync(Guid eventId);
    Task MarkEventAsFailedAsync(Guid eventId);
}
```

Here is the implementation of my interface:

> `public class EventLogService : IEventLogService`

```
{
    private readonly EventLogContext _integrationEventLogContext;
    private readonly DbConnection _dbConnection;
    private readonly List<Type> _eventTypes;

public EventLogService(DbConnection dbConnection)
{
    _dbConnection = dbConnection ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dbConnection));
    _integrationEventLogContext = new EventLogContext(
        new DbContextOptionsBuilder<EventLogContext>()
            .UseSqlServer(_dbConnection).Options);

    _eventTypes = Assembly.Load(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().FullName)
        .GetTypes()
        .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith(nameof(IntegrationEvent)))
        .ToList();
}
public Task MarkEventAsFailedAsync(Guid eventId)
{
    return UpdateEventStatus(eventId, EventStateEnum.PublishedFailed);
}

public Task MarkEventAsInProgressAsync(Guid eventId)
{
    return UpdateEventStatus(eventId, EventStateEnum.InProgress);
}

public Task MarkEventAsPublishedAsync(Guid eventId)
{
    return UpdateEventStatus(eventId, EventStateEnum.Published);
}

public async Task<IEnumerable<IntegrationEventLogEntry>> RetrieveEventLogsPendingToPublishAsync(Guid transactionId)
{
    var tid = transactionId.ToString();

    return await _integrationEventLogContext.IntegrationEventLogs
        .Where(e => e.TransactionId == tid && e.State == EventStateEnum.NotPublished)
        .OrderBy(o => o.CreationTime)
        .Select(e => e.DeserializeJsonContent(_eventTypes.Find(t => t.Name == e.EventTypeShortName)))
        .ToListAsync();
}

public Task SaveEventAsync(IntegrationEvent @event, IDbContextTransaction transaction)
{
    if (transaction == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(transaction));

    var eventLogEntry = new IntegrationEventLogEntry(@event, transaction.TransactionId);

    _integrationEventLogContext.Database.UseTransaction(transaction.GetDbTransaction());
    _integrationEventLogContext.IntegrationEventLogs.Add(eventLogEntry);

    return _integrationEventLogContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
private Task UpdateEventStatus(Guid eventId, EventStateEnum status)
{
    var eventLogEntry = _integrationEventLogContext.IntegrationEventLogs.Single(ie => ie.EventId == eventId);
    eventLogEntry.State = status;

    if (status == EventStateEnum.InProgress)
        eventLogEntry.TimesSent++;

    _integrationEventLogContext.IntegrationEventLogs.Update(eventLogEntry);

    return _integrationEventLogContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

}

Comment: You have not registered an implementation of your interface. You have instead registered the type Func<DbConnection, IEventLogService>. What you really want to do is registering the concrete type EventLogService as the implementation for the interface IEventLogService

Comment: Thanks @EnricoMassone. My actual problem was I have another service that uses IEventLogService and it was configured incorrectly. Thank you for your help :-D